# form border is invisible but existing

Tags: vb.net

I attached a picture where 2 form are supposed to be side by side no space: [picture with the 2 forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeBiS.png)

I know they should be side by side touching because I open the small form to the right with a click on "Palette Chart"

On click of the button it is just a simple code that should do what I expect:

```
    PalChart.Location = New Point(Me.Left + Me.Width, Me.Top)
    If PalChart.Visible = False Then PalChart.Show()
```

Even if there seem to be a space, I think it's a border that would be invisible, because when clicking in the space between, the form is being clicked.

I'm trying to help a friend with it and I'm stuck. Using Visual Studio 2022.

Edit: With talks in the comments, I realized it's the style of my default Windows. It has actually a bigger border than it appears for all program, it's barely noticeable, just shadowy. Here is an example with [Snipping Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFfN8.png).

So given this is BorderStyle, how do I do it so it is actually shown as big as it is, clearly? None of the available one does it:

Here are available [BorderSyles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzNwF.png).

Comment: There's no point using `Me.Left + Me.Width` when there's a `Me.Right` property. Similarly, you wouldn't use `Me.Top + Me.Height` when there's a `Me.Bottom` property. Those two properties are read-only and are literally calculated from the other four.

Comment: What is the `BorderStyle` of each form? Note that each form has a `ClientRectangle` property, which represents the bounds of the client area specifically. You can use them in your calculations to determine exactly where to position the second form. For instance, you might use `Me.ClientRectangle.Right` to get the right edge of the first form without regard for its non-client border width. Note that you'll still be setting the `Location` of the second form based on its non-client dimensions, so you'd have to subtract the width of its border too.

Comment: It looks like at least part of the reason is that Visual Styles are disabled. Is that because you have turned them off in Windows or because they are not enabled in that application? If it's a Windows setting, you might find that any code you write will behave differently on a system with Visual Styles enabled.

Comment: The fact that so many of the `Labels` appear screwed up on that form suggests that the UI needs some significant work, so you may even find that a fix for this problem doesn't work when other problems get fixed. It might be worth working out why that form is so screwed up in general first. Also, it appears to be using a scroll bar where it should be using a `TrackBar` control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney silly me, I now use Me.Right (same result though). Border Style is FixedSingle for both (not many choice, would have love blue like window XP). For the ClientRectangle it's weird, I tried using only Me.ClientRectangle.Right and it's weird, the other one pops almost in the middle... the ClientRectangle.Right seems to be worth half the Width of the form? As for the Visual Styles, dunno what that is I'll be looking it up. Oh and yeah labels are not yet placed, that is a WIP

Comment: With regards to visual styles, it is how the appearance of forms and controls changed from Windows 2000 to Windows XP. Your screenshot looks like the app is running on Windows 2000.

Comment: I just tested and any app, even notepad, when I am at same space distance those forms have, the cursor turns into an arrow to edit window size, meaning all application are bigger than they appear, they all have like an invisible border around them which is weird - dunno how to fix it. Fix could either be code or Visual Styles. If fixing it in code, it will appear wrong in other computers... If fixing my base Visual Style (I never edited it I wasn't even aware of those) it will look wrong on other computers.

Comment: Best example if Snipping Tool - it cannot be resized, so if I clicked within the invisible border, I have the arrow, but it does nothing since I'm clicking on the window - not beside it. Would there be a way to set borders in my program so they are seen as what they actually are? I will post a picture of snipping tool which has a shawdowy border

Comment: darn I saw you wrote it's the style of Windows 2000! I have Windows 10 and it always looked like that (every program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this has to do with default Windows 10 display of form. So it would show correctly on computer that have other settings for border display.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).